# how do i restore the Calculator tile to Windows 8 Start Screen?

Tags: windows-8

I suddenly lost the Desktop tile and more from my Windows 8 Start Screen and I could not find them in the search option. From your site I restored the Desktop tile. So, how do I get the tile for Calculator and another program as well?

Comment: If typing Calculator does not bring up a result you have bigger fish to fry this your missing Calculator tile.  If it does then right click on the result and add it back.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just start typing "Calculator" on the Start Screen, then right-click on the result for the search and select "Pin to Start" to add the tile to your Start Screen.

If you're having problems finding the Calculator app, make sure that when you search you are selecting "Apps" from the right side of the screen.

[Here's a video showing the process.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/adding-apps-websites-to-start)

Comment: but i all ready told that, in my pc i don't found the calculator tile..then what should i do..? [ actually i have same problem with desktop tile but i found the link for Desktop, and then the desktop tile will appear on stat screen.]

Answer (score 1):

If this happened "suddenly" - which I'm assuming means without anyone doing it - is possible something corrupted Windows' start screen. Since you couldn't actually find the Desktop tile - which can't be uninstalled that I know of - it sounds likely that's what happened. You may want to do a backup and refresh the PC.